# redirecting to a different url

Tags: html, node.js, routes

**App.js:**

```
var express         = require('express'),
    app             = express(),
    path            = require('path'),
    mongoose        = require('mongoose'),
    Schema          = mongoose.Schema,
    fs              = require('fs'),
    news            = require('./JavaScriptFiles/news.js'),
    bodyParser      = require("body-parser");


app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/news_update");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "news")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "cssFiles")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "JavaScriptFiles")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));


var newsSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    header: String,
    description: String, 
    brief: String,
    image: String

});

var News=mongoose.model("News",newsSchema);

// News.create(
//     { header: "afksajsfja  aj ajidjj  ", image:"https://i.gadgets360cdn.com/large/Samsung_m62_1616415136411.jpg?downsize=950:*&output-quality=80&output-format=webp", brief:"sakjdsahd sdks jis jdisjdia", description:"sakjdsahasdhsaud usah das9duhasdhaius dhamsiuhd uiahddiuas hmduisahui haifhasu ias hiuah "
//     },function(err,news)
//     {   if(err)
//         {
//         console.log(err);   
//         }
//         else
//         {
//             console.log("newly created news");
//             console.log(news);
//         }
//     });



app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
   
});
app.get("/index",function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});
app.get("/home", function(req,res){
    res.render('home')
});
app.get("/about", function(req,res){
    res.render('about')
});
app.get("/contact", function(req,res){
    res.render('contact')
});
app.get("/news",function(req, res){
    // removing all contents of db 
    // get data from the news database
    News.find({},function(err,allNews){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.render('news',{news:allNews});
        }
    })
 
});
app.post('/news',function(req,res){
    var header=req.body.header;
    var brief=req.body.brief;
    var description=req.body.description;
    var image=req.body.image;
    var newNews ={header:header, brief:brief, description:description, image:image};
    // news.push(newNews);
    // adding new campground to the database
    News.create(newNews,function(err,addedNews){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log("news added successfully");
            res.redirect("/news");
        }
    })
    // res.render("/news");
});
app.get("/news/new",function(req,res){
    res.render("new_news")
});
app.get("/preBuilt",function(req,res){
    res.render('preBuilt')
});
app.get("/Gadgets",function(req,res){
    res.render('gadgets')
});
app.listen(8080);
```

**new_news.ejs:**

```
<%- include ('../partials/header')%>
<h1 class="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-around">Add a new NEWS</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="width: 50%; margin: 3% auto">
            <form class="jsutify-content-around" method="post" action="/news">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" text" name="header" placeholder="header" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" text" name="brief" placeholder="brief" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" text" name="description" placeholder="description" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" text" name="image" placeholder="image" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info">Submit</button>
                <div class="form-group"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<%- include ('../partials/footer')%>
```

**news.ejs:**

```
<%- include ('../partials/header')%>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="news.css" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h3>Welcome to the NEWS Section</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mx-4" style="margin-top: 7%">
    <div class="d-flex bg-dark">
        <div class="d-flex col-md-9 col-8 flex-wrap bg-info justify-content-around">
            <% news.forEach(function(news1){%>
            <div class="d-flex col-lg-3 col-12 col-md-6 bg-primary mb-2 m-lg-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="<%= news1.image %>" alt="Card image cap" />
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">
                            <%=news1.header %>
                        </h5>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            <%= news1.brief%>
                        </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%}); %>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex col-md-3 col-4 bg-danger">this is try</div>
    </div>
</div>
<%- include ('../partials/footer')%>
```

**header.ejs:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #b0e0e6">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2dee66e886.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="navbar.js"></script>
        <script src="searchBox.js"></script>
        <style>
            .changeColor {
                transition: 500ms;
                background: transparent;
              }
              .changeColor.scrolled {
                background: black;
              }
              .navbar-light {
                transition: 400ms;
              }
            </style>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top changeColor">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">TTS</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="font-size: large" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <button class="rounded-lg btn-sm" type="submit">
                        Login<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I click on home button present on `/news` it redirects me to `/home` but when I try to do the same thing on `/news/new` it redirects me to `/news/home`. the same happens whenever I click any other button on the navigation bar. I have added the header file using `<include>` and I want my navigation to redirect to `/home`.

How do I fix this?

I'm using `node.js` for the development

Comment: try to use res.redirect('/home') to redirect to /home path

Comment: where exactly am I suppose to add that?

Comment: Use absolute path. So instead of `href="home"` use `href="/home"`

Comment: it worked perfectly well, thank you so much @Molda